# How to return IDs with different values between field rows

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to return IDs with different values between segments:

```
| id    | segment     | quantity |
|-------|-------------|----------|
| 12345 | Control - A | 1        |
| 12345 | Control - B | 1        |
| 98765 | Control - A | 0        |
| 98765 | Control - B | 1        |
```

Output:

```
| id    |
|-------|
| 98765 |
```

I have tried CASE logic, partitioning, etc. but am wondering the optimal approach.

Comment: now one could argue that `0` is different to `1` the same way that `1` is different to `0` - which would make both valid for output ;)

Comment: You are debating about a detail that has so little importance that it was omitted ;)

Answer (score 2):

I find using the EXISTS clause to be the easiest to read in these types of cases, but the other answer with the self-join should also work just fine.

```
select distinct id 
from t1 where exists 
  (select 1 
   from t1 t1_alias 
   WHERE t1.id = t1_alias.id and 
   t1.segment != t1_alias.segment and 
   t1.quantity != t1_alias.quantity)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the optimal approach, but you haven't mentioned it, I would try something like this:

```
select
    distinct t1.id
from
    table t1 inner join 
    table t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.quantity != t2.quantity and t1.segment != t2.segment
```